# Filter POST data in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a view in django that is going to save HTML data to a model, and I'm wondering how I might go about filtering it before saving it to the model? Are there built in functions for it? I know there are template filters, but I don't think those help me in this case.

What I'll be doing is getting the content of a div via JQuery, sending that to a view via ajax, then saving it to a model.

Comment: what do you mean by '"filtering it"

Comment: Similar to PHP's htmlspecialchars I suppose. Just something to make it 'more safe' to save raw HTML to a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django takes care of safely storing strings in the database. html is a worry when *displaying* to the user, and django provides some help there as well, escaping html unless explicitly told not to

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for, thanks. Any tips to displaying it back?

Comment: Assuming it takes care of safely storing the string, if I print the data back out will it be in the 'safe' format, or will I have to use the something like `{{ object.data|safe }}`?

Comment: as you can see if you try, it is escaped by default. Note, however, that this is only safe if inserted as html, not e.g. as a string inside some javascript. (for that, use json.dumps)

Answer (score 0):

You can use urllib module and these functions : http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#utility-functions